# Python How to use sep=" " only between second and third item

Tags: python, function, printing

I have a question about the print function.

```
print("Welcome to", a, "This is your new world")
```

How can I use `sep=" "`
to get a full stop between whatever a is and "This is your new world", but not between "Welcome to" and whatever a is?

I am using Python 3.

Basically I want to print this:

Assuming `a` is "cake".

```
Welcome to cake. This is your new world
#              ^ is the full stop I am talking about.
```

It won't accept the question like this so here is more detail: 
I have tried Google for help but it didn't help as it is all more basic and it is just talking about using the separation function when there are two items of text.

Comment: Why don't you just `print("Welcome to", a, ". This is your new world")`? It sounds like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. If the output is always the same and always includes ". " just before "This is", hard-coding it is simpler than using a fancy separation function. If you're ever going to extend this in the future though, it makes sense to do it right like you're asking.

Comment: @anandsun because that would include extra space between the value of `a` and the period, resulting on `Welcome to cake . This is your new world` that's exactly what OP is trying to avoid

Comment: @nosklo Just remove the trailing space from a. Use a[:-1] or something.

Comment: @SamCraig `a` doesn't have a space. The space comes from the `print()` function. By default it uses spaces to separate the arguments when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to achieve what you are describing some better than others.

#### 1st way

We can first keep the syntax that you have but make slight changes:

`print("Welcome to " + a + ". This is your new world")`

As you may notice, I added a space after "to" and a period and space before "This". I also replaced the commas with `+`

#### 2nd way

We can use %s. This basically converts the variable to string and allows you to write the whole output without needing to use the + which is more pythonic.

`print("Welcome to %s. This is your new world" % a)`

#### 3rd way

This is probably the way most people would approach it.

`print("Welcome to {}. This is your new world".format(a))`

An ever better version of this is what nosklo mentioned:

`print("Welcome to {name}. This is your new world".format(name=a))`

---

[This website](https://pyformat.info/) may help you further.

Comment: Thank you. If I had another {one of these}, would I do: .format(name=a, banana=b)? Assuming the other one was banana in the text.  Also what is the brackets thing called?

Comment: Yup exactly. The brackets are called curly brackets. They are usually used for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function uses the same `sep` to all arguments. If you want different separators you can build the string yourself and pass it as a single argument to `print()`.

```
print("Welcome to {name}. This is your new world".format(name=a))
```

Another option is to not use `sep` and include the separators when necessary yourself:

```
print("Welcome to ", a, ". This is your new world", sep="")
```